# Datastructure and algorithm

Tags: c#, winforms, data-structures

Topic:
Simulate data structures and algorithms of a database management system
Request:

- Data storage
- Query: support Select, Insert, Update query

I plan to do it on winform, there are **create table, select, delete, update** commands just like sql. But I don't know how to write those functions in C#. Does anyone have documents on those basic functions of SQL? please help me.
Can anyone with knowledge of this topic guide me step by step? I really don't know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modern programming there is a tendency to separate your data (= model) from the way the your data is displayed (= view). To connect the view to the model, we need an adapter class: the viewmodel. Together these three classes are abbreviated as MVVM. Consider to read something about this.

The advantage of separating the model and the view, is that you can reuse the model for other views, you can change the model without having to change the view, or change the view without changing the model. Finally, it is way easier to unit test the model classes without needing a form.

I mention MVVM, because you try to mix the database handling with WinForms. The database handling (model) has nothing to do with how you display the fetched data.

**Back to your question**

Apparently you have no problem displaying the fetched data (yet). So let's focus on how you fetch your database data in C#.

There are two major methods: one is using SQL, via a DbConnection and a DbCommand. The other often used method is using entity framework and LINQ.

You mentioned that you already have the SQL to fetch the data. So I'll focus on that method. If you are interested in entity framework, consider reading [Entity Framework Code First](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/what-is-code-first.aspx) and do some experimenting, when there's nothing on TV.

You want a method to create a table. Since tables are working together, my advice would be not to create a method that creates one table, but create a method that creates all tables of your database in one call.

```
public void CreateAllTables()
{
    const string sqlText = "Create if not exists TableCustomers (
         Id int,
         FirstName Varchar(30),
         ...
```

The exact syntax depends a bit on the SQL dialect that you are using: MicroSoft? MySql? SimpleSQL? Well, I think you know the Sql text better than I do. On to how to send this the database:

```
    using (var dbConnection = new DbConnection())
    {
        using (DbCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            dbCommand.CommandText = sqlText;
```

Now there are several methods to execute a dbCommand:

- Retrieve a sequence of items: `DbCommand.ExecuteReader`
- Retrieve exactly one object: `DbCommand.ExecuteScalar`
- Execute only, no data returned: `DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`

In this case: we only execute the command. Before communicating with the database we have to open the dbConnection:

```
            dbConnection.Open();
            dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

`DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` has a return value: the number of affected rows. Sometimes it might be handy to check this to see if errors occurred.

Now to fetch some data

```
public IEnumerable<Product> FetchStudentsByLastName(string lastName)
{
    const string sqlText = "Select Id, FirstName, LastName, ...
        From tableStudents
        Where LastName = @LastName;"
```

Note that my SQL has `@LastName` as parameter!

The beginning is the same as in CreateTables:

```
using (var dbConnection = new DbConnection())
{
    using (DbCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        dbCommand.CommandText = sqlText;
```

To fill the parameter:

```
        // associate the parameter in the SQL text with the value:
        dbCommand.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastName);
```

Now we are ready to open the dbConnection and execute the query. We expect to fetch several rows, so we have to use `DbCommand.ExecuteReader`:

```
        dbConnection.Open();
        using (DbDataReader dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
```

The `dbDataReader` contains the fetched data. use `DbDataReader.Read` to find out if there are still rows to read. If so, use `GetInt32`, `GetString` etc to read the cells in each row:

```
            while (dbReader.Read())
            {
```

Apparently there is a row. We selected Id as column 0, FirstName as column 1, LastName as column 2, etc:

```
                Student fetchedStudent = new Student
                {
                    Id = dbReader.GetInt32(0),          // column 0 is an Int32
                    FirstName = dbReader.GetString(1),  // column 1 is a string
                    LastName = dbReader.GetString(2),
                    ...
                }

                yield return fetchedStudent;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To add a student we do someting similar: Create the DbConnection and the DbCommand. Fill the DbCommand with the SQL text and `AddWithParameter`.

The difference is: we don't expect several rows as return, we only want the Id of the added Student.

How to return the Id in the command depends on the SQL dialect that you are using. In SQLLight it would be something like this:

```
const string sqlText = "INSERT INTO tableStudent (
   FirstName, LastName, ...) Values(@FirstName, @LastName, ...);
   SELECT last_insert_rowid();"
```

After adding the new student, this SQL text will return the Id of the student.

Create the DbConnection and the DbCommand. Then:

```
dbCommand.CommandText = sqlText;
dbCommand.AddWithValue("@FirstName, firstName);
dbCommand.AddWithValue("@LastName, lastName);
...
```

Open the database, and execute the query with only one result: `ExecuteScalar`, return the returned Id as an int:

```
dbConnection.Open();
return (int)dbCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

### Resume

I've shown you how to communicate with a database using DbConnection and DbCommand.

I showed how to add parameters to your SQL text.

To fetch rows of data use `ExecuteReader` and Read row by row, using `DbReader.Read`, and `DbReader.GetString(colum number)` etc.

I showed how to execute without returning value: `DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`. Used in create table, delete table, update row in table, delete row from table.

And finally, I showed how to return one value: `DbCommand.ExecuteScalar`. Used to return the Id when adding a new row.